# Installation Error for KDE Plasma Desktop in Ubuntu 15.10 "All Shell Packages Missing"

Tags: linux, ubuntu, dependencies, package, kde-plasma

This is my first question here. First I should state that I am a bit of a newbie to linux. I was trying to install KDE 5 Plasma in an Ubuntu 15.10 installation on my Dell XPS L502x laptop. When I first installed Plasma Desktop, I noticed some graphics bugs, one of them being a lag in the mouse movement leaving a trailing "after image" (Sorry if this isn't the right term). So I thought  to reinstall it by removing KDE desktop completely. But now, after I installed it again, I get a black screen with this Installation error "All Shell Packages Missing". I am able to open "Yakuake" though since I set it to auto start on startup. Can anyone give me some suggestions to rectify this?

PS: GNOME still works fine. I am able to login to it and there are no errors.

Edit:
I am attaching the log of the startx command [here](https://anotepad.com/notes/rxenr4)

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem and solved it by installing `plasma-desktop-data` deb package. That will install the default shell so `plasmashell` will not complain anymore.

Comment: I had already reinstalled the os through a distribution upgrade. I tried this and it reverted me back to GNOME. I had to reinstall kubuntu-desktop and then it worked. Thanks anyway! Cheers

Comment: On Gentoo it was the kde-plasma/plasma-meta for the full version or kde-plasma/plasma-desktop for the light version.

Comment: What is plasma-desktop-data? That is not an official plasma-component; anyone knows in which plasma part this is?